# C# / WinAPI - Monitoring a Memory Region

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, memory-management, native-code

I was wondering if there is a way to monitor a particolar memory region for changes. I'm using the following method in order to open a process and obtain a collection of its used memory regions:

```
internal static MemoryProcess OpenProcess(Process process)
{
    IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccess.Desided, true, (UInt32)process.Id);

    if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return null;

    IntPtr processAddress = new IntPtr();
    List<MemoryRegion> memoryRegions = new List<MemoryRegion>();

    while (true)
    {
        MemoryBasicInformation info = new MemoryBasicInformation();

        if (VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, processAddress, out info, MemoryBasicInformation.Size) == 0)
            break;

        if (info.Allocation.HasFlag(MemoryAllocation.Commit) && info.Type.HasFlag(MemoryType.Private) && ((info.Protection & MemoryProtection.Readable) != 0) && ((info.Protection & MemoryProtection.Protected) == 0))
            memoryRegions.Add(new MemoryRegion(info.BaseAddress, info.RegionSize));

        processAddress = new IntPtr(info.BaseAddress.ToInt64() + info.RegionSize.ToInt64());
    }

    if (memoryRegions.Count == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return null;
    }

    return (new MemoryProcess(processHandle, memoryRegions));
}
```

I saw a lot of applications doing this. Cheat Engine is one of them. Let's say I open a Google Chrome Tab process and I search and find a specific value (the string "stackoverflow") within it's memory:

[image]

Now, i use that tab to browse another, completely different, website and I see those address values changing:

[image]

Last step: I close that Chrome tab killing its corresponding process:

[image]

So... of course there MUST be a sort of monitoring for memory regions. And, in fact, there is:

[image]

Using Process.Exited event is not enough to achieve a real time update of memory addresses values I think... so, how can I do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use .NET directly for this.  You might able to use a Win32 API via interops, but AFAIK there is no .NET API for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can intercept `VirtualAlloc` called in target application, and combined `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` to original flags, system will keep track of this allocated memory region, then you can call the `GetWriteWatch` function to retrieve the addresses of the pages that have been written to since the region has been allocated or the write-tracking state has been reset. This looks a lot of work to do though.